# A moving charge or an accelerating charge produces Electromagnetic waves.?

Tags: electromagnetism

[![  A moving charge or an accelerating charge produces Electromagnetic waves.? ]][30]

Answer (score 0):

A moving charge does not change its energy content, hence it could not radiate. A charge in negative acceleration or circular motion loose energy, and this in the form of EM radiation. In positive acceleration it could radiate too.